# How to use socat to transfer serial commands in a script over TCP/IP?

Tags: python, tcp, serial-port, raspberry-pi, ethernet

I have a web application that will constantly post some queries and get replies from a device through the serial port on Raspberry Pi. Like this:

```
 @cherrypy.expose
 def login (self, **data):
    passcode = data.get("passcode", None)
    print "logging in using passcode %s"%passcode ,type(passcode)

    import serial
    import time
    #open connection
    serialport=serial.Serial ("/dev/ttyAMA0", 9600, timeout=0.5)
    #write in user sign in code
    serialport.write("\x03LI%s\x0D"%passcode)

    reply=serialport.readlines(1)
    print reply, type(reply)
    #check if log in success
    if not "00" in reply[0]:
        if "FE" in reply[0]:
            state="engineer"
        else:
            state="user"
    else:
        state="none"
    print state
    time.sleep(1)
    return state
```

Currently I am using direct 3 wires (**gnd, txd, rxd**) from Raspberry Pi to the device's (**gnd, rxd, txd**). The **serial port** of Raspberry Pi is /dev/ttyAMA0 and say the device has an **IP** of 10.0.0.55. i could send netcat command one at a time like this:

```
nc 10.0.0.55 1001
^CLI1234^M  //this is an example of the serial command sent to the device from Raspberry Pi terminal
```

How should i do it with `**socat**`? I don't want to change the script but just to manipulate some configuration in socat (or something else) that would forward the command to the device's IP. I want to get rid of the 3 wires connected to R-Pi UART. i hardly find examples on socat that would suit this requirement (or may be i don't know what keyword i should use). Please enlighten me :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: The `socat` equivalent of your `nc` command would be `socat STDIN TCP:10.0.0.55:1001` but I am very confused about what this has to do with the CherryPy application that accesses the serial port directory. That application doesn't seem to have any reference to TCP on port 1001 anywhere!

Comment: yeah it currently doesn't that's why i would like to find out how to do it? :s for the nc, i was saying i could connect it that way but not with cherrypy or any python script, simply line by line of command.

Comment: What exactly would you like to achieve? My understanding is that you have some device and RPI connected together over serial port. You have a simple app, running on RPI to read/write from the serial port. Socat is just a bridge between 2 file descriptors of almost any type. If all you want to do is to connect over TCP to RPI and forward the serial connection data over that TCP connection - socat will work. You can use this: http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat-ttyovertcp.txt . Also, I do not understand how you would like to get rid of the serial wires.

Comment: @ChrisKoston thanks for your comment. You are right, those are what i want to achieve. Because connecting the serial wires seem redundant if connection through the ethernet is possible? so i thought i can just remove it. so just to clarify, i can just run the python script (which will send serial command), and do some configuration to forward the commands to ethernet port?

Comment: Is your setup like this: 
DEVICE<---serial--->RPI<-----TCP------>CLIENT  ???

Comment: @ChrisKoston currently my client is on RPI itself (localhost), it is something like DEVICE<--serial and/or TCP -->RPI which means the DEVICE can either use a serial or ethernet connection to communicate.